# HttpClient is not working properly on RESTful API

Tags: angular, rest, angular6, angular-httpclient

Delete method is not giving me an error since I am passing **1000** as an argument which is not present in the 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' json document. Instead, it just removes the selected document. I searched everywhere but I didn't find any code which specifies how to resolve this problem. Any help would be appreciated as I am new to Angular Framework.

Below is my Code of Service file(post.service.ts)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { NotFoundError } from '../common/not-found-error';
import { AppError } from '../common/app-error';
import { BadInput } from '../common/bad-input';

// For handling Http Requests
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostService {
    private url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    private userUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getPosts() {
        return this.http.get(this.url);
    }

    deletePost(id) {
            console.log('Service Id: ', id);
            return this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + id)
                .pipe(
                    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                        if (error.status === 404) {
                            console.log('You screwed');
                            return throwError(new NotFoundError());
                        }
                        return throwError(new AppError(error));
                    })
                );
```

This is my Component File(post.component.ts)

```
deletePost(post) {
    console.log('Post Id is: ', post.id);
    this.service.deletePost(1000)
        .subscribe(
            response => {
                let index = this.posts.indexOf(post);
                this.posts.splice(index, 1);
                console.log(response);

            },
            (error: AppError) => {
                if (error instanceof NotFoundError) {
                    alert('This post has already been deleted');
                } else {
                    alert('An Unexpected error occurred.');
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getPosts()
        .subscribe((response) => {
            this.posts = response;
            console.log('Posts: ', this.posts);
        }, error => {
            alert('An Unexpected error occurred.');
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

This is my Component.html File(posts.component.html)

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li *ngFor="let post of posts" class="list-group-item">
        <button (click)="deletePost(post)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>{{ post.title }}
    </li>
</ul>
<br>
```

Comment: Does your services working properly ? I don't understand your problem, What do you mean with "it just removes the selected document." ? And why you are putting parameter as "this.service.deletePost(1000)", for testing purposes? I you can reproduce your issue with stackblitz, I can help.

Comment: Yes, my services are working properly. "It just removes the selected document" means-When I try to click the delete button on the front-end, it removes that element from the front end. Instead it should throw an error saying that "This post has already been deleted". this.service.deletePost(1000) is for testing purpose to make sure whether it is throwing an error or not.

Comment: That means your this.service.deletePost(1000) operation is succesfully (OR), you are having problem with "catchError" property on your service. (post.service.ts)

Comment: Yes. It's just I don't know which part is having problem.

Comment: I will share my services with you, so you can use it as example. Give me a sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API that you are invoking returns a JSONObject. Not an error. See the POSTMAN invocation of the API

[image: POSTMAN invokation of the API].

Since this is not an error, CatchError is not executed.

**UPDATE**
Since there is no error, your success part executes. Which takes the index of the returned object in the existing `posts` array. If you log the index to console, you can see it will be -1.
Without checking whether the index is found or not you are passing it to splice.
`array.splice(-1,1)` will remove the last element from the array. Hence the `li`
element getting deleted.

More on [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

You have to check whether the index of returned object is present in your array. then perform splice.

Comment: Thanks. So what should I add/remove to execute that catchError block?

Comment: catchError block only gets executed in case of errors. If you want to test it, you can simply change the url , so a 404 is thrown.

Comment: Yes. I understood why CatchError is not executed. But in the http request I am passing 1000 as an argument, so the "li element" should not be deleted from the component since there is no such document in the posts whose id is 1000.

Comment: I have printed the value of index on console. It is showing the index of the element present in the posts array on which the delete operation is performed. Also, it's not showing the value of index as -1 when I am passing 1000. Then what's wrong in my code?

Comment: What is the index value being printed?

Comment: 1,4,8, etc. Depending upon the element's index in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Im using this approach, I hope it helps.
(If you return your service result as Observable, it will be easier to manage it's results from component side.)

UPDATE:

**myService.ts**

```
deleteDocumentService(documentId: number): Observable < any > {
    var result: Observable < any > = this.http.delete < any > (`${this.apiBaseUrl}document/${documentId}`);
    return result;
}
```

**myComponenet.ts**

```
import {myService} from './Services/myService'

deleteDataSubscription: Subscription;
data: any;


constructor(public _myService: myService) {}

//you will fire this function when button is clicked
deleteDocument(id:number) {
    //call your delete service here
    this.deleteDataSubscription = this._myService.deleteDocumentService(id)
        .subscribe(
            (success) => {
                //if your delete operation is succesfully, do what ever you want here
                //now you can fire a function or trigger to remove entry from your table
            },
            (error) => {
                //if your delete operation is unsuccesfully, console log error.                      
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
);
}
```

Comment: Okay, Thank you. It would be better if u can just tell me what would be the code for- If the given document doesn't exist in the backend then it should not delete "li element". Because here the "li element" is getting deleted irrespective of whether the document exist or not. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you. I get it now.